# Adding comment out for matlab-mode

Tags: comment, matlab

How can I apply `M-;` to comments out blocks in matlab-mode? Currently it only adds comments at the end of line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use a generic "comment/uncomment line or region DWIM" kind of function that works in any major mode.

### Generic comment DWIM function

Here is the function I use:

```el
(defun endless/comment-line-or-region (n)
  "Comment or uncomment current line and proceed to the next line.
With positive prefix, apply to N lines including current one.
With negative prefix, apply to -N lines above.
If region is active, apply to active region instead."
  (interactive "p")
  (if (use-region-p)
      (comment-or-uncomment-region
       (region-beginning) (region-end))
    (let ((range
           (list (line-beginning-position)
                 (goto-char (line-end-position n)))))
      (comment-or-uncomment-region
       (apply #'min range)
       (apply #'max range)))
    (forward-line 1)
    (back-to-indentation)))
```

### Tweaking the bindings for `matlab-mode`

```el
;; Unbind the M-; key from `matlab-mode-map'
;; `with-eval-after-load' will work in emacs 24.4 and newer versions
(with-eval-after-load 'matlab
  (define-key matlab-mode-map (kbd "M-;") nil)) 

;; For emacs 24.3 and older versions use `eval-after-load' instead
;; of `with-eval-after-load'. Note that `eval-after-load' accepts
;; only a single quoted form.
;; (eval-after-load 'matlab
;;   '(define-key matlab-mode-map (kbd "M-;") nil)) 

;; Define the M-; binding globally
;; This binding will be effective in any major-mode that does not
;; have that major-mode-specific M-; binding
(global-set-key (kbd "M-;") #'endless/comment-line-or-region)
```

---

[**Source**](http://endlessparentheses.com/implementing-comment-line.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this doesn't work. It behaves the same. I also tried it in python files, and they behave the same.

Comment: You need to save the above pieces of code somewhere in your emacs config and then restart emacs. If it doesn't work even after that, report on what you see on doing `C-h k M-;` while in the \*scratch\* buffer and while in a buffer with `matlab-mode`.

Comment: I missed it before: When emacs loads it reports: 
Symbol's function definition is void: with-eval-after-load

Comment: @user2476373 You are probably using emacs 24.3 or an older version. `with-eval-after-load` was introduced in emacs 24.4. See if you can upgrade the emacs version on your machine (latest as of today is version 24.5). If not, I have updated the solution with an alternative (commented out) to use `eval-after-load` instead of `with-eval-after-load` for emacs 24.3 or older versions.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, all you should need is:

```
(add-hook 'matlab-mode-hook (lamba () (local-set-key "\M-;" nil)))
```

so as to stop matlab-mode from overriding the default <kbd>M-;</kbd> binding.  And please report this problem to the matlab-mode authors so they can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/redguardtoo/evil-nerd-commenter

supports even emacs23.4, all you need is just one line setup:

```
(evilnc-default-hotkeys)
```

There many commands you can use, but if you want to comment out blocks separated by empty line, you just need `M-x evilnc-comment-or-uncomment-paragraphs`